# Swagger Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Required property 'parcel_Triclops_Data' expects a non-null value

Tags: c#, swagger

I have the following classes:

```
public class TriclopsParcelDataViewModel
{
    public long ParcelId { get; set; }
    public string ParcelSkuType { get; set; }
    public string ParcelDescription { get; set; }
    public Parcel_Triclops_Data Parcel_Triclops_Data { get; set; }
}

public class Parcel_Triclops_Data
{
    [Key]
    public long ParcelId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public double WidthCm { get; set; }
    public double HeightCm { get; set; }
    public double DepthCm { get; set; }
    public double WeightKg { get; set; }
    public string TriclopsImage { get; set; }
}
```

TriclopsParcelDataViewModel is given as a result in one of my swagger/api endpoints.

I have then generated a client from the swagger definition.

When i call the function i get the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Required property 'parcel_Triclops_Data' expects a non-null value. Path '[0]', line 1, position 99.

When i look at the json returned it looks like this:

```
[{"parcelId":13121,"parcelSkuType":"luggage-xl","parcelDescription":"","parcel_Triclops_Data":null},{"parcelId":13122,"parcelSkuType":"luggage-xl","parcelDescription":"","parcel_Triclops_Data":null},{"parcelId":13123,"parcelSkuType":"luggage-xl","parcelDescription":"","parcel_Triclops_Data":null},{"parcelId":13124,"parcelSkuType":"luggage-xl","parcelDescription":"","parcel_Triclops_Data":null}]
```

I get the feeling i need to override the json serialization settings in the generated client but unsure if i am correct.

Can anyone shed any light please?

Comment: Are you using nullable reference types? If you change the property to `public Parcel_Triclops_Data? Parcel_Triclops_Data { get; set; }` does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should look like this:

```cs
public class TriclopsParcelDataViewModel
{
    public Parcel_Triclops_Data ParcelId { get; set; } //changed from long to Parcel_Triclops_Data
    public string ParcelSkuType { get; set; }
    public string ParcelDescription { get; set; }
    public Parcel_Triclops_Data Parcel_Triclops_Data { get; set; }
}

public class Parcel_Triclops_Data
{
    [Key]
    public long ParcelId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public double WidthCm { get; set; }
    public double HeightCm { get; set; }
    public double DepthCm { get; set; }
    public double WeightKg { get; set; }
    public string TriclopsImage { get; set; }
}
```